# open mapping theorem for several variable analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Is open mapping theorem true for a analytic function in several variable ?

I've encountered a problem, which can be solved easily if that's true. But I couldn't find that after doing some Googling

Comment: Do you mean a holomorphic function $f\colon U \to \mathbb{C}$ where $U\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ is open, or $f\colon U \to \mathbb{C}^m$, in which case, what is the relation between $n$ and $m$?

Comment: I want first one

Comment: Then look at $h_{\mathfrak{w}}\colon \lambda \mapsto f(\mathfrak{z} + \lambda\cdot \mathfrak{w})$ for a fixed $\mathfrak{z}\in U$ and some $\mathfrak{w}\in\mathbb{C}^n \setminus \{0\}$. If $f$ is non-constant, some $h_{\mathfrak{w}}$ is non-constant, thus ...

Comment: @DanielFischer Doesn't the case for any $m \leq n$ also follow similarly from your last comment, or maybe I am missing something?

Comment: @user346998 If $m > n$, then a holomorphic function $f\colon U \to \mathbb{C}^m$, where $U\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ cannot be open. If $1 < m \leqslant n$, then non-constantness of $f$ still doesn't imply openness, there could be a nontrivial relation between the components.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, I see now that this argument does not work. Is the result true though ($m \leq n$), or is there a reasonably easy counterexample?

Comment: @user346998 For $m>1$, you need more than just that the function isn't constant. An easy example is $f(\mathfrak{z})=(g(\mathfrak{z}), h(g(\mathfrak{z})))$, where $h\colon\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic. It is sufficient that the (complex) Jacobian has rank $m$ everywhere. But that's not a necessary condition. In the case $m=n=1$ the condition is that the derivative doesn't vanish identically (on any component of the domain), the corresponding condition would be that the determinant of some $m\times m$ submatrix of the Jacobian doesn't vanish identically. That's probably sufficient.

Comment: This topic is nearly 2 yrs old so I just reply here for reference. @DanielFischer the condition on the determinant of the Jacobian submatrices is not sufficient as the example $(z,w) \mapsto (z,zw)$ shows: the image of the unit polydisk contains the origin but is not a neigh thereof because in the image the second variable has a modulus less* than the modulus of the first variable (*or equal if z=0).

Comment: Thanks @Arnaud, that's a nice simple example.